# How to convert Canvas pic in PNG pic with an absolute link?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

```html
            <!-- Create a canvas to combine text and image -->
                    
            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="450" height="600">  
            </canvas>

            <!-- Script for displaying the current date in dd-mm-year format -->

            <script>
            var d = new Date();
            var month = new Array("01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12");
            var tt = d.getDate() + "." + month[d.getMonth()] + "." + d.getFullYear();
            </script>


            <script> 

            /* Transfer the value of the current date to the canvas, and transform it into a picture */

            var cx = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");
            cx.font = "15pt Arial";
            cx.fillText(tt, 62, 300);
                    

            /* In order for the date to be on top of the piece of paper, move the element to the foreground */

            cx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";     


            /* Add a picture of our dude with a document to the canvas */

            var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"), 
            context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                 
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = "https://i.imgur.com/TCDGYdh.png";


            /* Move the picture with the dude to the background */

            img.onload = function() {
                var pattern = context.createPattern(img, "no-repeat");
                context.fillStyle = pattern;
                context.fillRect(0, 0, 450, 600);
            };

            </script>
```

*I apologize for the welter, I'm just learning.* :)

I want to make a picture on which the date will change every day, in accordance with the actual date. I tried create a picture via canvas in HTML with JS.

Please take a look at my code, I have detailed everything there with the comments.

I would like to have a link to this picture, which can be coppied, and everyday the date on the picture must be actual.

**So, what I want. I want the resulting picture, when the right mouse button is pressed, to have option 'Copy image address', like this:**
[How I want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNZnl.png)

**As you can see, my current result picture looks like this:**
[As I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acs3y.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well there are multiple methods, One is having the image inside a tag

```
<a href="#">
   <img border="0" src="some.jpg" width="100" height="100">
</a>
```

Other is that to place the link absolute to the image.

```
<div class="position-relative">
    <img border="0" src="some.jpg" width="500px" height="500px">
    <a href="#" class="position-absolute"><span class="no-opacity no-visibility no-pointers"></span></a>
</div>
```

Also, if there is any other scenario, then put your code for further review

Comment: You misunderstood me, unfortunately :)

I have corrected the starter post and added my code - please take a look and help me if you can.